# Using an iMac as an additional monitor for Mac Mini M1

Tags: display, mac-mini, airplay

I am aware that the Mac Mini M1 has an infuriating limit of two monitors. However, it appears that you can attach an AirPlay device as an additional monitor.

I have a retired iMac running AirServer or Reflector (I’ve tried both), and I can use it as an extended monitor on my Mac Mini. AirServer does it a little more transparently, though there seems to be less lag with Reflector.

The limitation with both is that AirPlay itself appears to have a limited resolution of 1080p, and so I don’t get the full benefit of the size and resolution of the iMac.

Unfortunately, the iMac is a little too old for built-in AirPlay support and too new for Target Display mode.

Is there some other software solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions already dealing with this topic of using a Mac of some type (MacBook, iMac, iPad, etc.) as an additional display to a computer whether it be another Mac or even a Windows machine.

- [Using iMac late 2013 as external monitor to HP EliteBook 820 G3 on Windows 10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384716/119271)
- [Connect another mac as secondary display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/398940/119271)
- [How can I use an iPad with a Retina display as an external monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/93736/119271)
- [How to use my iMac 2017 as a second monitor for my MacBook Pro mid 2012?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/381502/119271)

#### Target Display Mode

<sup>(Just putting this here to address the question)</sup>

iMac computers [prior to 2014 supported Target Display Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389357/119271),  Potentially your iMac might support it (you mentioned it was "too old" for AirPlay) but Mac computers running  High Sierra or later couldn't connect to it.  This makes an Apple-centric hardware solution untenable.

#### Software Solutions

In the links of similar question linked above, it comes down to about two different solutions:

- [Luna Display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/).  This uses a hardware based dongle to connect a computer to a Mac or iPad as a secondary monitor
- [AirParrot 3](https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/). This allows you to turn any device including AppleTV and Chromecast into another monitor you can stream/mirror to.

The problem with these solutions is the limited amount of bandwidth available to send high definition video with a high refresh rate reliably.  This is why you're not getting the resolutions you're looking for.

#### Final thoughts

There are good to excellent apps out there to stream and extend a desktop, but they are not designed for "production use."  They are for setting things up in an ad-hoc manner. I've personally used SpaceDesk on a Windows machine to extend the display of a laptop to my iPad.  It was great when I was in the local Panera working on financials, but when I got back to my desk, I didn't give it a second thought since I had my multi-monitor setup.

Don't try and bodge this.  Restore that iMac back to it's glory and sell it or get into retro computing.  For the secondary display, get a quality monitor.